# Will the asterisk (*) next to merged articles in my Google Scholar profile disappear?

Tags: google-scholar

After merging two articles in my Google Scholar profile, an asterisk (*) shows up on the profile next to the merged items. Will it disappear after a while, or will it remain forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While *forever* is a long time, article that I have merged over a year ago are still marked with the asterisk. I would assume that this will not be automatically removed, and will remain until Google decides to change the design.